# How does etcd handle reads/writes during a network partition?

Tags: distributed, etcd

I am looking for something to use as a simple service registry and am considering etcd. For this use-case availability is more important than consistency. Clients must be able to read/write keys to any of the nodes even when the cluster is split. Can etcd be used in this way? It doesn't matter if some of the writes are lost when things come back together as they will be quickly updated by service "I am alive" heartbeat timers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also new to etcd. What I have noticed is when network partitioning happens, reads still work for the nodes which are not in main quorum. They will see inconsistent data.

As for the writes they fail with "Raft internal error"

Comment: What's your etcd version? I've tested it with etcd3.3.8, my cluster has three nodes, when 2 of them are down, the remain node can't accpet any request even read-only request.